# How do I troubleshoot electrified radiator plumbing?

Tags: electrical

I disconnected and moved a convector-style radiator out of the way when tiling a bathroom wall. The pipes are black iron. My hands were wet and when I happened to touch both the supply and return pipes at the same time, after the radiator had been moved out of the way, I got an electric shock. Not as strong as touching a 120V hot wire by any means, maybe around 20% of that, just judging by the tingling sensation. Strong enough that I wanted to let go of it quickly.

How do I proceed to troubleshoot this?

[image: boiler junction box with metal wire jacket]

[image: metal jacket back at the panel]

Comment: How old is the oldest wiring in the house (alternatively, what's the age of the house)? That would help those in the know to identify patterns that were acceptable at the time and no longer are

Comment: FYI that green presumably equipment grounding wire is not attached to the metal box in an approved manner. It should go under a permanent grounding screw in a threaded hole in the box, or an approved grounding clip. All metal boxes sold these days have those grounding tapped holes from the factory.

Answer (score 17):

The first step in troubleshooting is to ensure you have a way of testing that the fault is present, without getting a shock, especially hand-to-hand or hand-to-foot.  Plenty of causes could lead to it being merely uncomfortable once, but very serious if things change.  An AC voltmeter (multimeter) between the two things you touched would be a good start.  It may read 120V despite your fairly minor shock, if the source is current-limited.

Then I'd turn off every breaker in the house.  The voltage should go away.  After that turn on breakers until it comes back. That will identify the circuit(s) that make it live.  Switch those off while you investigate the earth fault.  You may also wish to check that the voltage on both legs stays at 120V as you do this.

With a 120-N-120V system and various historic practices around earthing and neutral, I'd be looking hard at any 240V appliances that have been (or rather with connections that have been) there for longer than your panel.

Comment: Thanks. 240V would be an electric stove and an electric wall oven; the wiring for each predates the panel.

Comment: ...unless the fault is a neutral/ground short (in some circumstances that can create an AC voltage) and the relevant breaker only disconnects live.

Comment: @abligh if there's a voltage present with them all off, the problem is unlikely to be fixable without professional help (whether from the power company or on the property) - which is worth learning. We know it's present with them all on. So it's well worth looking for the transition. That's partly why I start all off then turn on.

Answer (score 9):

Odds are good that somewhere along the line, someone used the plumbing as the electrical ground for the whole house. This used to be acceptable, but no longer meets modern code, since

- significant parts of modern plumbing are non-conductive plastic
- it's far too easy for someone to introduce plastic between the grounding connection & the water supply entry point, breaking the grounding path
- water supply lines are usually plastic now, too, and won't serve as a ground anyway

A short somewhere in the house would electrify the metal piping within the house that now cannot run to ground, thus *you* get the shock.

It's also possible that there is a short somewhere in the boiler/control system that is electrifying the radiator plumbing.

To troubleshoot

- Look for a (most likely) bare wire running from your electrical panel to your plumbing somewhere. If you find that, you should get a new ground wire run from your main panel, and that might require an electrician and an inspection.
- Look for loose connections, bare wires, broken insulation in and around your water heater. Fix any issues you may find there.

Comment: Thanks. The wire running from a relatively new panel over to the relatively new boiler is two-conductor with a metal protective sheathing. The green ground wire from the boiler's control box is attached to the metal junction box. The connections appear to be intact back at the panel, so would that continuity provide a ground?  (pls see pics)

Comment: Presuming the metal is properly grounded at both ends and that it's legal to use it as the ground then yes. However, I'm talking about the main ground for the entire house. Since you say the panel was recently replaced, it's likely to be properly grounded (not via water pipes), but it's always a good idea to confirm this.

Comment: Varies by area. In my area (at least as of 1-1/2 years ago) some jurisdictions require 2 ground rods, others require 1 ground rod + water pipe near entrance to house.

Comment: It doesn't even matter if the pipes are properly grounded, electricity will follow *all* paths to ground. It's just that the majority will follow the easiest path, which might be why the OP didn't get a full shock.

Answer (score 8):

I'd start by turning off breakers until you find the circuit that is causing the problem. That lets you prioritize putting the house in "safe" mode while you look for the actual cause. (Test whether power is still there with a meter, not with a hand...)

Once you have the circuit identified, you can try making other disconnections to further determine the failure point. If you have a wire tracer (signal injector and detector) available, that may let you track it down without having to turn power back on.

Comment: Would it be better (ie safer) to turn all the breakers all off, then turn them on, one-by-one, until you find the culprit?

Comment: That would be my approach, since what you have now is apparently unsafe. Some people have stronger injections to having to reset more clicks than necessary, or may not have a flashlight (though every phone is a flashlight these days)

Answer (score 2):

I'm all for DIY solutions, but I'm also all for safety, which is why I'm posting the obvious (and obligatory) answer:

Don't do this yourself, but rather call an electrician or plumber. They have the tools and experience to figure out this issue safely that you might not have.

Unless you feel yourself capable to follow every step of the other answers safely, don't risk your or your family's safety.

This project isn't for everyone (and I include future readers in this answer).

That said, feel free to post back anything "out of the ordinary" you discovered so future readers can learn, too.